# Работа с UI в разных потоках

Tags: android

Добрый день. Есть кнопки: СТАРТ, Кнопка 1 и Кнопка 2. При нажатии на кнопку СТАРТ, текст кнопки 1 должен измениться через 5 сек. а текст кнопки 2 должен измениться через 10 сек. Сама же кнопка СТРАРТ в этом интервале времени должна быть кликабельна и рабочая. Подскажите пожалуйста как это реализовать.

Comment: Как относится заголовок вашего вопроса к тексту вопроса?

Answer (score 1):

Есть такой класс `android.os.Handler`; у него есть метод `postDelayed`; это то, что тебе нужно.

Если хочешь выполнять в фоне какое-либо действие, то тебе в помощь AsyncTask.